# What exactly is a "File Number"?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6

I'm working in some C# code that had earlier been converted over from VB6 and it does lots of file I-O.  All over the place I see this:

```
  fn = VBNET.FileSystem.FreeFile();
```

...followed by *VBNET.FileSystem.FileOpen()*, some file I-O, and then *VBNET.FileSystem.FileClose()* .

The call to *FreeFile()* generates a "file number", which is required to open the file.   But what IS a file number and how do you release it back to the system when you're done with it?

The documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.freefile.aspx doesn't seem to say, but it does say that an exception would be thrown if "more than 255 files are in use", which implies to me that it would be a good idea to release them when I'm done with them.

**N.B.** - I understand that there are better file-IO libraries to use but this is what we're stuck with until we have resources to rewrite this stuff, so I just want to understand it.

Comment: FreeFile reuturns a handle file which can be used for IO; it is analogous to a stream and is under the surface is probably a wrapper for a filestream.  I think closing the file you associate with the handle/number releases it

Comment: Literally what it says, it is a number.  Between 0 and 255.  In .NET it is an index into an array of VB6File objects.  FileClose() 'releases' the number again.  Long-term you'll probably want to replace it with FileStream or StreamReader/Writer but that's a lot of work.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.freefile(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those VB6 commands (FreeFile, FileOpen, FileClose, LOF, etc.) were present at least as far back as QBasic. I expect that the file number was originally an MS-DOS file handle.

A quick google search came up with these links:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269030 - Maximum file handles in MS-DOS is 255, which may explain that limit. (Not really the subject of the page, but first link that I found.)
- http://stanislavs.org/helppc/file_handles.html - The INT21 functions listed seem to match up with the old style file commands.

Back in QBasic (if memory serves), the `FileOpen` command opened the file and reserved the file handle. The `FileClose` command closed the file and freed the handle.

`FreeFile` was just a convenience method to get an unused file handle: if you knew that you didn't have (for example) file #1 open, then you could just call `OPEN "C:\DOS\RUN" FOR INPUT AS #1` and not bother calling `FreeFile`. You would still close it with `CLOSE #1`

I can't remember if that changed in VB6. As Hans Passant mentioned, internally in .NET the file number is now just an index into an array of VB6File objects. [FileSystem.vb](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/FileSystem.vb)

Comment: It looks like you're right about File Close.   That's very asymmetrical because File Close is the closure for file Open.   It's like having two left-parentheses and then one right-parenthesis that's some sort of super-parenthesis with the power to close two open-parens.   Anyway thanks!

Comment: @user316117 If memory serves, back in QBasic, FileOpen is what actually reserved the file handle, and FileClose is what freed the file handle. FreeFile was just a convenience function to get a file handle that hadn't been opened yet. So the symmetry is that FileOpen opens a file handle, and FileClose closes it. I'll clarify my answer.

Comment: @user316117 FreeFile does not actually "do" anything with the files. You could call it repeatedly and you'll get the same value back, until you actually open the file.

Answer (score 5):

In early version of BASIC, pre-objects, when you wanted to do I/O to a file, you needed to tell the interpreter which open file you wanted to use by its number. The runtime had a table of open files, and the file number was basically an index into that table. The concept is similar to a file handle, as you would have used via the Windows API, but every BASIC program had it own set of file numbers.

Normally, the way you would do file I/O would be something like the following:

```
OPEN #1, "path\to\file"
PRINT #1, "Stuff I want in the file"
CLOSE #1
```

You would be responsible for keeping tracking of which file numbers you had opened, what files they pointed to, etc.

For simple programs, this isn't a big deal, but when you start to write modular programs, with shared subroutines and external libraries and such, that system becomes unworkable. If you're writing a logging routine, for example, you have to somehow select a file number for your log file that you can guarantee is never being used anywhere else, or bad things would happen.

The `FreeFile` function is VB's answer to this problem. Calling `FreeFile` returns the next available slot in the open files list, which you can then be sure no one else is using. In pseudo-code, it would be like doing this in the above code:

```
I = 0
WHILE ALREADYOPEN(#I) 
  I = I + 1
WEND
OPEN #I, "path\to\file"
PRINT #I, "stuff to go into file"
CLOSE #I
```

`FreeFile` basically does the equivalent of the the loop, except it already knows which file numbers are used and which aren't so it can just give you an answer. Otherwise, the I/O works exactly the same: once you *have* your free file number, you open it, read/write to it, and close it again.

Comment: But how does it get released?   Once the system or the runtime has given me a file number how does it know when I'm done with it?    As I said in my question, this software does a lot of file I-O so if the max is 255 I could easily imagine it running out if there's not some way to tell the system when it's done with a file number.

Comment: That's what the CLOSE/FileClose does. Once you close a file number you can't use it again, and it's available to use again in a new OPEN statement.

Comment: `Close` without a parameter closes all open files.