# Equivalent of Open for input as - in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, migration, vb6-migration

Hello I am migrating an application from vb 6 to .net and I don't know what is the way to translate the Open PATH_IN For Input as intfile(0) into the vb.NET syntax, thanks for your help in advance and sorry for my english, here is the code code :

```
 Open PATH_IN For Input As intFile(0) 
For intContador = 1 To intDefinicions - 1
        intFile(intContador) = FreeFile()
        Open Targetes(intContador).Out For Output As intFile(intContador)
Next
    While Not EOF(intFile(0))
        intRegs = intRegs + 1
        Line Input #intFile(0), sRegistre

    If Len(sRegistre) >= 146 Then
            sTipusFitxerEMV = Mid(sRegistre, 144, 3)
            sTipusFitxerEMV = verificarTipusFitxerHOST(sTipusFitxerEMV)
            bTipusFitxerEMV = True
            ciCVV = Mid(sRegistre, 147, 3)
            sRegistre = Left(sRegistre, 143)
        Else
            bTipusFitxerEMV = False
        End If

        sBIN = Left(sRegistre, LEN_BIN)
        bTrobat = False
        For intConta = 1 To intDefinicions - 1
            If Targetes(intConta).BIN = sBIN Then
                bTrobat = True
                sNewReg = "$" & transCaractersEspecials(sRegistre) & Chr(Hex2Dec(22)) & ComposaBanda(sRegistre, Targetes(intConta).Banda)



                If Targetes(intConta).EMV Then
                    sNewReg = sNewReg & ComposaEMV(sRegistre, Targetes(intConta).Identificacio, Targetes(intConta).PEK, Targetes(intConta).Banda, ciCVV)
                Else
                    iPosNoEMV = Len(sNewReg)
                    sNewReg = sNewReg & String2Hex(sNewReg)
                    sNewReg = Mid(sNewReg, 1, iPosNoEMV)
                End If

                If bTipusFitxerEMV And Targetes(intConta).EMV Then
                    escriureFitxerEMV sNewReg & "#END#", intConta, sTipusFitxerEMV
            Else
                    Print #intFile(intConta), sNewReg & "#END#"
            End If

            End If
        Next
        If Not bTrobat Then
            MsgBox "It do not exist" & vbLf & vbCr & sRegistre, vbCritical, "Atention"
    End If
Wend
```

Comment: Do you want to convert to the .NET way of doing things (in which case the answer from MarkusEgle is the way to go) or do you just want to do the minimum necessary to get it working in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file reading you need to change it to use StreamReader object

e.g.

```
Using streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(PATH_IN)
    While Not streamReader.EndOfStream
        sRegistre = streamReader.ReadLine()
        ...
    End While
End Using
```

Comment: I just found  this :

  FileOpen(intFile(0), PATH_IN, OpenMode.Input)
        For intContador = 1 To intDefinicions - 1
            intFile(intContador) = FreeFile()
            FileOpen(intFile(intContador), Targetes(intContador).Out, OpenMode.Output)
        Next
        ' Llegim tots els registres,
        While Not EOF(intFile(0))
            intRegs = intRegs + 1
            sRegistre = LineInput(intFile(0))

Is that correct ? or I am wrong ?

Comment: That FileOpen is still using intFile(0), that is a FileHandle and old style. [MSDN How to: Read From Text Files in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-text-files) says: _"To read a file a single line of text at a time, use the OpenTextFileReader method of the My.Computer.FileSystem object. The OpenTextFileReader method returns a StreamReader object. You can use the ReadLine method of the StreamReader object to read a file one line at a time."_

Comment: Please check ["Those VB6 commands (FreeFile, FileOpen, FileClose, LOF, etc.)"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22847396/3090544)